# C#: Sending file to PHP script using UploadFile method, need to send additional information

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I am currently building a music application in C#. I need to associate songs with specific users. I am sending the file to a PHP script, which then uploads the song Title and Filepath to a MariaDB database. I need to send the user's username from C# to the PHP file so I can store it as a foreign key along with the song Title and Filepath in the database. I need to be able to pass the username to the PHP at the same time that the MP3 file is sent to the PHP from C#.

Thanks.

PHP

```
<?php

$fileExistsFlag = 0; 
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

//Variable that gets the username when passed from the client side(html)
$username = $_POST['username'];
//Variable that gets the username when passed from the client side(C#)
//$Uusername = $_POST['Uusername'];

$link = mysqli_connect(<sever details>) or die("Error ".mysqli_error($link));

//Checking whether the file already exists in the destination folder 
$query = "SELECT Title FROM songs WHERE Title='$name'"; 
$result = $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if($row['Title'] == $name) {
$fileExistsFlag = 1;
}   
}

//If file is not present in the destination folder
if($fileExistsFlag == 0) { 
$target = "songs/"; 
$fileTarget = $target.$name;    
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];    
$result = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$fileTarget);


//If file was successfully uploaded in the destination folder
if($result) {   
echo "Your song <html><b><i>".$name."</i></b></html> has been successfully uploaded!";

$query = "INSERT INTO songs(Title,Path,Uusername) VALUES('$name','$fileTarget','$username')";
//$query = "INSERT INTO songs(Title,Path,Uusername) VALUES('$name','$fileTarget','$Uusername')";
//$query = "INSERT INTO songs(Title,Path) VALUES('$name','$fileTarget')";
$link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));
}

else {  
echo "Sorry. There was an error uploading your file.";
}
mysqli_close($link);
}


//If file is already present in the destination folder
else {
echo "The song <html><b><i>".$name."</i></b></html> already exists. Please rename the file and try again.";
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

C#

```
private void uploadSongs()
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
    //string usernameEntry = LoginUsernameEntry.Text.ToLower();

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {

            files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
            paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                filelist.Items.Add(files[i]);
                this.nowplaying.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                //sendUsername();

            filelist.Items.Add(files[i]);

            MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName);


                //variable that the LoginUsername is set to so it can be passed to the PHP
                string usernameEntry = LoginUsernameEntry.Text.ToLower();                        

                //code that uploads files to the server by creating a new instance of the WebClient class
                System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();

                //setting the content type of the files being uploaded
                Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");

                //reading in the file as bytes, using UploadFile to call the PHP "POST" the file, with the name being "openFileDialog.1.FileName"
                byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("URL", "POST", openFileDialog1.FileName);

                //send the resulting bytes as a string to the server
                string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);

                string response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);

                MessageBox.Show(response);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not include your server username /password details. Next include your C# post method

Comment: Since your `$_FILES` is populated I'll assume you sent it as multipart/form-data. I believe you can add `StringContent` along with the file if you are using `HttpClient` class. You can get it as `$_POST`in PHP

Comment: I can get the file uploaded and info sent to the DB from HTML to PHP. I can get everything except the username when going from C# to PHP. And I am using the `WebClient` class also and not `HttpClient` class. Which should I  be using?